# How to print generated data with absolute positioning?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, printing

I have a website powered by WordPress with a commercial plugin which generates an HTML ticket when someone RSVP an event.

My client designed the ticket as an image, and wanted me to plug the transaction-generated data (QR code, transaction ID, transaction date and time) at relevant places on that design.

I used CSS with absolute positioning to do so. I also used `@media print` to design the page the way it should be printed, my thinking being that since A4 has fixed dimension, my printing rules would be universal for anyone printing on A4. I've discovered the hard way it doesn't work this way.

I looked on here, found some unsupported CSS such as `page` and overall it seems it's impossible to achieve within CSS3.

The ticketing plugin uses a JS library browser-side to generate the QR Code, whilst PDF generation should happen server-side as I understand it. Implementing a PDF generation solution would mean integrating a PHP QR Code Library.
I wonder if there might be another route than PDF generation that people with the knowledge I don't have at the present can think of?

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: I have actually done all of this already! My question is general so there is no particular minimal code to be given, as in many related questions I found. No viable workaround has been found through my research on stackoverflow (no PDF generation, no `page`, etc.) Hope my question is deemed answerable!

Comment: Alas no. We do not know what you tried so we run the risk of telling you to do exactly what you tried. The best way IS pdf, perhaps we could have found how to avoid conflicts